# Is there a way to display the framerate in the BGE standalone runtime/EXE?

Tags: game-engine, frame-rate

I'm going to be handing out the package/runtime for different people on differing hardware to test, and I'd like to be able to display a framerate counter in a corner during the running of the standalone runtime. I can do this in the 'standalone' player within Blender, but not the 'exported' runtime outside of Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the blenderplayer arguments

```
blenderplayer.exe

usage:   blenderplayer.exe [--options] filename.blend

Available options are: [-w [w h l t]] [-f [fw fh fb ff]] [-c] [-g gamengineoptions] [-s stereomode] [-m aasamples]
Optional parameters must be passed in order.
Default values are set in the blend file.
...
  -g: game engine options:

       Name                       Default      Description
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
       show_framerate                 0         Show the frame rate
...
example: blenderplayer.exe -w 320 200 10 10 -g noaudio c:\filename.blend
example: blenderplayer.exe -g show_framerate = 0 c:\filename.blend
example: blenderplayer.exe -i 232421 -m 16 c:\filename.blend
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know where I can actually find these arguments? I've skimmed around and people talk about editing them but I haven't the slightest idea how to bring them up.

Comment: Open a console at your OS. Then execute the blenderplayer without any arguments. It will print your the options of that version. The above text is an excerpt of this output.